# How to disable auto changing tabs to spaces in the code in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, whitespace, indentation, autoformatting

How to disable auto changing tabs to spaces and removing empty lines, whitespaces in the sourcefiles after it opened?

In other words if the line contains tabs and spaces in one line Idea shouldn't change them. For example if file contains "-->-->....-->public void setAttribute();" Idea shouldn't change tabs to spaces or spaces to tabs. I can disable all autoformattig.

Answer (score 5):

To restate the problem, you want the editor to **not** affect the whitespace indentations. Spaces should remain spaces and tabs should remain tabs.

I'm having a similar problem. It looks like IntelliJ has this feature:

`Settings > Editor > Code Style`,
`Indents Detection` section,
`Detect and use existing file indents for editing` option

Unfortunately, I don't think I can get it to work as expected for myself (version 2016.3.6), but it seems to be working for others.

Here's the [original jetbrains blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/intellij-idea-14-will-detect-code-styles-on-the-fly/) about it.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution helped in my case really well.

Answer (score 4):

There is an option 'keep indents on empty line'

[image]

Comment: The more important here for the question is "Use tab character" - when not checked, tabs are automatically replaced by spaces when typing.

Comment: This worked for me in Intellij 2021.3.1 version. issue of auto indent addition resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Java: `Settings > Code Style > Java > Tabs and Indents > Use tab character`. You can do the same for other languages too.

Comment: I meant if the line contains tabs and spaces in one line Idea shouldn't change them. For example if file contains "-->-->....-->public void setAttribute();" Idea shouldn't change tabs to spaces or spaces to tabs. I can disable all autoformattig.

Comment: Exactly ... the question is not "how do I configure the IDE to use tabs for tabs (instead of spaces)". It's "how do I stop IntelliJ from auto-converting tabs to spaces? This is so god damn annoying ... you end up with commit diffs full of whitespace changes that you never wanted. Why did they think this was a good default?

Comment: @TomFennelly Seriously, our code review system is showing literally hundreds of diffs that are only whitespace changes, because we moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ recently.  So freaking annoying, I hate IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Besides noted IDE settings, please check if *.editorconfig* file exists in your project. The file may silently override IDE settings.

Answer (score 0):

In **Editor - Code Style - Java/JSON/etc - Tabs and Indents** are two checkboxes:

1. **Use tab character** - when not checked, Idea **replaces tabs by spaces** while typing
2. **Keep indents on empty line** - when not checked, Idea removes tabs and spaces from lines where is no other content